# FB Graph Error: "(#100) User must be on whitelist"

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm calling

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{the id of one of my app's actions}
```

and getting the following response body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) User must be on whitelist", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I'm an admin on the app in question.  Anyone have any idea what this error means?

Comment: Did this ever get solved? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Brett Yeah, I got it and fixed it in the way, I answered. Please check, if u still have that problem

Answer (score 3):

I got this error today and the problem was that some of the `fields were missing`. So, do `check your URL`, where you are sending the request.

Like in my case I had to make a request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userID/myAppName/
```

Instead, I was making request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com//myAppName/
```

That should fix your problem as it did mine :D

Comment: Thanks Prashant, and sorry for never accepting.  Our project actually moved around this another way and it would take me hours to go back, find the code, reproduce the issue, and try your fix.  The takeaway for me: turn on email notifications so I find out right away when someone answers my question!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and while I'm not positive what I did to fix it, I think it was linking the action to an objet (the 'Connected object type' form field) that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally got this issue when requesting **insights** endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/<ad_id>/insights?fields=account_id,account_name,action_values,actions,ad_id,ad_name,adset_id,adset_name,app_store_clicks,buying_type,call_to_action_clicks,campaign_id,campaign_name,canvas_avg_view_percent,canvas_avg_view_time,canvas_component_avg_pct_view,clicks,cost_per_10_sec_video_view,cost_per_action_type,cost_per_estimated_ad_recallers,cost_per_inline_link_click,cost_per_inline_post_engagement,cost_per_total_action,cost_per_unique_action_type,cost_per_unique_click,cost_per_unique_inline_link_click,cpc,cpm,cpp,ctr,date_start,date_stop,deeplink_clicks,estimated_ad_recall_rate,estimated_ad_recallers,frequency,impressions,impressions_dummy,....
```

Finally have find out that the **impressions_dummy** field was causing the problem, so when have removed it from the request the issue was solved.